by lazy {} causing a cast exception in production / hashmap loosing values after assigning
we have a code that looks somewhat like this small example:
// this is a class that is injected into a view model, it is injected once, as a parameter
// it is used in multiple functions in the view model, some of them may happen one after another or even at once
class UseCaseProvider(repository: Repository) {
    val useCaseMap = HashMap<Class<*>, UseCase<*, *>>()
    private val clearFiltersUseCase by lazy { ClearFiltersUseCase(repository) }
    // maaaany more usecases made in the exact same way...
    
    private fun <INPUT, OUTPUT> register(useCase: UseCase<INPUT, OUTPUT>) {
        useCaseMap[useCase::class.java] = useCase
    }
    
    internal inline <reified T: UseCase<*, *>> get(): T {
        if(!useCaseMap.containsKey(T::class.java)){
            when(T::class) {
                ClearFiltersUseCase -> register(clearFiltersUseCase)
                // maaaany more similar lines
                else -> throw IllegalStateException("UseCase not registered")
            }
        }
        return useCaseMap[T::class.java] as T
    }
}
// example usage in the view model: 
// useCaseProvider.get<ClearFiltersUseCase>().invoke() 
// .invoke() is always suspend

and we get a class cast exception, null being cast into an UseCase class, any ideas why that might be happening?
we have a similar usecase provider in another module, but instead of using lazy & the register function it just creates and saves the instances in a hashmap once the provider is created and it does not crash, thus my suspicion that somehow lazy is at fault here?
I'm accepting any ideas (race conditions for lazy {}, thread-safety were my only ideas, but I wasn't able to reproduce the crash)

Do you mean you call useCaseProvider.get() from multiple threads? HashMap is not thread-safe for concurrent modifications. Your code in get is also no entirely thread-safe, so we may register the same use case multiple times, but I believe this shouldn't cause CCE. By default lazy should be thread-safe.

Ok, so it is possible that is writing concurrently, but then we would see concurrent modification exceptions, and reading from a map is thread safe, also as I mentioned we have a similar useCaseProvider with a map and it has no crashes

I doubt we have any guarantees map will throw ConcurrentModificationException. As a matter of fact, documentation mentions this exception only if using iterators. And in my tests hashmap didn't throw, but its contents were incorrect. I can't draw conclusions about your alternative implementation and I don't say your observed problems are for sure caused by what I said, but the above code is clearly not thread-safe.

hmmm, valid point, but what I did try is to write a custom function to run multiple threads and run random useCases, I know it may be luck based but I had no crashes... do you think making it thread safe by using ConcurrentHashMap or something will fix it?

ConcurrentHashMap should fix the problem I described (still, there is another bug where we may register the same use case multiple times). But I can only guess if this is really the problem you face. I believe technically speaking it may cause CCE, however, this is probably very rare. See this code: https://pl.kotl.in/2-FqIrRs3 We always store a value under the same key, but sometimes we get incorrect value, probably from another key. This would result in CCE in your case.

Actually, when I looked closer into my case, the value was always null, not just another value. Which makes sense, because even if we accidentally put an entry into an incorrect bucket, we should still not be able to get an incorrect value, because equals won't match on keys. So the question is if as T throw NPE or CCE in the case of null. But again, this is just making educated guesses :-)

I guess you can post this as an answer and I will accept it once we actually test this in prod c:

but I still don't get how after assigning map[id] = id in your code on the next line if (map[id] != id) println("Error") actually prints... may be the late hour or the amount of hours I spent on the issue, but that's... magic, oooor is it that one thread assigns map[id] = id then goes to the if statement and during that time another thread reasigns that exact map[id]? but then how is map[id] null?

HashMap simply isn't thread-safe. If one thread is mutating it and at the same time another thread either reads or writes into it, many different weird situations may happen. HashMap doesn't at all guarantee any specific behavior in this case. And no, one of points of my example was that each thread writes to different keys, so they should never overwrite same keys between themselves. But the map simply cannot work correctly in the multi-threaded environment.

@broot was right, but to share more insights on why we got null on a value we just assigned
(warning: may not be 100% correct, but it seems to explain why this provider crashes and the other one, that assigns each usecase when the provider is created, doesn't):
When one thread writes to a DYNAMIC SIZE hash map, and another one tries reading from it, IF the hash map has to resize and rehash (done under the hood) it seems it creates a copy with 2x the size of the previous map and fills the keys (with nulls as values) and starts rehashing the values... and if a thread reads at that EXACT time, it will get null as a value from a key that didn't have a null value before
ways you can fix it:

initialize all objects inside of the hashMap when the Provider is created (no new writes = no resizing needed)
use a ConcurrentHashMap
somehow limit the size of the hashmap (and starting with an inital size that will 100% fit your case)
as we did: remove the hashmap completly :D

